# jQuery not loading in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I first deployed my application to a shared server on Godaddy and everything was working perfectly. I just moved to a dedicated server still on Godaddy and am experiencing jQuery issues. I cannot search in Gridview.  The error in the console is

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).yiiGridView is not a function

I have tried clearing the assets folders in web/assets same issue.

When i change my index.php to development mode, i get an Internal Server Error and nothing displays.

When i change my index.php to production mode, the site loads but i cannot perform any jQuery function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Enable developer mode in your browser (usually F12) and look at the network page to see which resources are not loading.

Comment: Thanks. Done that. All resources have a status of 200

Comment: Maybe you add two or more jquery libs on the same page. Have you checkout this